# How to describe such a brick wall, tiny cracks in it and the other side of the wall cannot be seen throgh the cracks?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to describe a brick wall in which there are some tiny cracks and they are not broken apart. In other words, the other side of the wall cannot be seen throgh the cracks.

I googled "cracked brick" and got lots of images, this one (img_1) almost meets my need

[image]

which suggests that "crack" might be suitable.

I also googled "crumbled brick" and got something like this (img_2)

[image]

which indicates "crumbled" is far away to describe my need.

How to describe such a brick wall?

Comment: 'Brick wall' is **two words**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey fixed. Thanks for your reminder~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Crumbling* suggests that parts have broken away, so maybe you could see through parts of a crumbling wall.

If you want to make it clear that you cannot see through the cracks in the brickwork, you could perhaps say:

- The bricks were *cracking*
- The bricks were beginning to crack
- Cracks were beginning to show in the bricks

As the cracks are just beginning, and the bricks are still in the process of cracking, there is no suggestion they have completely cracked in two.

Cracks which are only visible and do not actually cause separation are known as *hairline cracks*, so you could also perhaps say:

- The bricks had hairline cracks.